# How to pass props to route without causing component to mount twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass props to my components through the accepted way from various sources like this [comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-291834881)

This is my current code

```
<Router>
  ...
  <Route path="/:id" exact component={() => <GymMain id={params.id} appointmentTypes={appointmentTypeList} />} />
  <Route path={`/:id/:name`} component={(props) => {
    const { params } = props.match;
    const aType = appointmentTypeList.find(at => at.uri === params.name);
    return <AppointmentType id={params.id} appointmentType={aType} />
  }} />
  ...
</Router>
```

However this causes the components to mount twice, once when you navigate into it and then when you navigate away from it (while navigating away old props are passed). This is happening because I am decorating my original component with an anonymous one as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572683/975932)  .

My Question is how can I prepare the props for child components based on the route params and then pass it on to the routed component. Thanks!

Comment: is the componentDidMount method called twice for GymMain and AppointmentType? Also did you try `render` instead of `component` prop

Comment: for both, let me try that, can you tell me what is the difference though?

Comment: render actually fixed this

Comment: Added an answer with the explanation

Answer (score 1):

There is a small difference between using `component` prop vs `render` prop to render a functional component.

As per the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component):

> When you use `component` (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from
>   the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to
>   the component prop, you would create a new component every render.
>   **This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component**.
>   When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or
>   the children prop (below).

Hence you see the above behaviour in your case. Change your code to use `render` prop and it would work fine

```
<Router>
  ...
  <Route path="/:id" exact render={() => <GymMain id={params.id} appointmentTypes={appointmentTypeList} />} />
  <Route path={`/:id/:name`} render={(props) => {
    const { params } = props.match;
    const aType = appointmentTypeList.find(at => at.uri === params.name);
    return <AppointmentType id={params.id} appointmentType={aType} />
  }} />
  ...
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way for doing so. 
you can use `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()` lifecylcle method to check incoming props.

```
UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
// check for your condition for updating component
 if (this.porps !== nextProps) { 
   this.forceUpdate()
}
 else {
    return
   }
}
```